# Why does linear probing work with a relatively prime step?

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic, hashtable, primes, modulo

I was reading about [linear probing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing) in a [hash table tutorial](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx#openaddr) and came upon this:

> The step size is almost always 1 with linear probing, but it is acceptable to use other step sizes as long as the step size is relatively prime to the table size so that every index is eventually visited. If this restriction isn't met, all of the indices may not be visited...

(The basic problem is: You need to visit every index in an array starting at an arbitrary index and skipping ahead a fixed number of indices [the skip] to the next index, wrapping to the beginning of the array if necessary with modulo.)

I understand why not all indices could be visited if the step size isn't relatively prime to the table size, but I don't understand why the converse is true: that all the indices will be visited if the step size is relatively prime to the array size.

I've observed this relatively prime property working in several examples that I've worked out by hand, but I don't understand why it works in every case.

In short, my question is: Why is every index of an array visited with a step that is relatively prime to the array size? Is there a proof of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider table size=4 and step size=2. You'd visit only the even-numbered (or only the odd numbered) slots.

Comment: Yes, that part he understood. But how about the reverse?

Comment: @wildplasser I understand that. See the paragraph "I understand why..." My question is why (for example) table size=4 and step size=3 visits every index. Why does it work in the general case?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem will probably help.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia about [Cyclic Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group)

> The units of the ring Z/nZ are the numbers coprime to n.

[Also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime):

> [If two numbers are co-prime] There exist integers x and y such that ax + by = 1

So, if "a" is your step length, and "b" the length of the array, you can reach any index "z" by

> axz + byz = z
>
> =>
>
> axz = z (mod b)

i.e stepping "xz" times (and wrapping over the array "yz" times).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid that I don't follow how cyclic groups apply to array indices, or why the equation ax + by = 1 applies to array indices, or what x and y represent, or how you reached axz = z (mod b).

Answer (score 2):

number of steps is `lcm(A,P)/P` or `A/gcd(A,P)` where `A` is array size and `P` is this magic coprime.

so if `gcd(A,P) != 1` then number of steps will be less than `A`
On contrary if `gcd(A,P) == 1` (coprimes) then number of steps will be A and  all indexes will be visited